# Set TextBox Value of Userform2 based on TextBox Value entry in Userform1

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Userforms "LoginForm" and "AMForm".

The user enters their UserID into "txtUser" text box on the LoginForm. When entry is accepted, AMForm opens. I want their UserID to appear in the top left of AMForm.

How can I set the textbox value in AMForm "txtAMFormID" to equal the value of "txtUser" in LoginForm?

```
Private Sub txtAMFormID_Change()
txtAMFormID = LoginForm.txtUser.Text
end sub
```

Comment: Hi is the txtAMFormID a label control? If so all you need to do is assign the label control the textbox value during AMForm initialization. `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Label1.Caption = UserForm1.TextBox1
  
End Sub`

Comment: Hi RCL, firstly, thank you for your reply. txtAMFormID is the name I have set of the textbox in "AMForm" userform. With your code Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() should this just be Private Sub txtAMFormID_Change() instead from my original code?

Comment: Hi, `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` is called for each userform before they appear. You will need to copy that code inside the userform and just copy your code from `txtAmFormID_Change()` and that should achieve your goal.

Comment: It works thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi posting my comment on the answer so this post can be marked as solved.

Is the txtAMFormID a label control? If so all you need to do is assign the label control the textbox value during AMForm initialization.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 
 Label1.Caption = UserForm1.TextBox1 
End Sub
```